# PHP: is file_get_contents() bypassing external download?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, download, mirroring

following issue:
I have a large file on my server (~2GB). 
A user who is logged in to my site can download this file from my server.

Unfortunately my server is not that strong. When many user downloading this file simultaneous they will all have very poor dl speed.

So I uploaded the file to google drive and generated a direct download link:
http://googledrive.com/host/[FILE_ID]

My code:

```
<?php
  $remoteFile = 'http://googledrive.com/host/[FILE_ID]';
  $filename = basename($remoteFile);
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  echo file_get_contents($remoteFile); 
?>
```

My question: is file_get_contents() really bypassing the dl or is this file going thru my server? If so, that makes no sense :[ ]

Comment: All you've done is store it elsewhere. This isn't going to resolve any bandwidth issues. You could always redirect the user to the direct download page instead.

Comment: But i want to hide the googledrive link. The user should not have a chance to get the googledrive link an share it. The download should only work if the user is logged in

Comment: If they don't see the google drive link, that means you are first transferring the file to your server, then transferring to the client, which doubles your bandwidth problem.  One solution might be to generate a unique google drive share link after every download, so that only your authenticated users can download, and links may not be used more than once.

Comment: My solution by now is to rent an other server, which can interprete php. Store the file there, create a php-script which streams the file if a certain token is used. The token will be fetched from $_GET

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique google drive share link after every download, so that only your authenticated users can download, and links may not be used more than once.